# How to create a .table extention jbehave file using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jbehave, jbehave-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin

I need to create a .table file to keep the data for Jbehave using intelliJ. 
(As an example like this ,org/trader/stories/trades.table  )
But .table file extension isn't populated when I create the file and mentioned that .table extension is not available.

Is there a separate plugin for that ?.

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA you can create files with any extensions, just associate it with a plain-text or try to use this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6629?pr=idea

Comment: Thanks a lot. As usual , File ---> New ---->File and enter name as trades.table. Is it right ?. Anyway I have already installed that plugin .

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, it is right and if IDEA doesn't have any plugins then it recommends you to choose file association, you can choose plain-text to be able to edit the .table files as plain-text files.